# Navigation menu bar

Tags: wordpress

In navigation menu bar clicking on home or service both tab color changes. Either it should change the color of clicked tab or it should remain the same.

[Site](http://tsalegal.in/)

Comment: service link contain same class of home page.....can you go to menu section and create service menu again by provide http://tsalegal.in/#service to custom menu link and check it...

Comment: @AshPatel I don't think it will resolve the issue because OP is trying to switch the section but user will remain on same page so `current` class will apply to both link. What OP needs to do is when user click on `Service` it should add `current` class to it by removing its `current` class from siblings.

Comment: @rohil, true..but if you check firebug service menu contain 'current' class on home page as well.it seems he had created service tab by drag home page from page section in admin menu screen.Because of it service section contain same class as home .so once he will create service menu from custom link section by provide suitable link it will work as it is and home class will not append to service menu as well.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed or not but there is `menu-item-type-custom` which means both the menu are created with custom links options.

Comment: Yes i already noticed it and because of it  both menu contain same class and created from home tab in word press admin

Comment: @rohil : i was bit confused to make clear about it..as i check in my local...both home menu and custom link would get same class untill we use same URL in custom link...so issue might be solve by keep only #service in custom URL instead of tsalegal.in/#service..I have tested in my local as well and it resolved problem...

Comment: Yah! that is the approach he should go with (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem.

Edit your home page and look at services section. i think you are using visual editor. so please remove your gap section from top of the services and put it above section.

Comment: No, It has nothing to do with visual editor. The problem is that service lies on home page so they both active at a time. However I have made the same color for both for active and inactive tab.

Comment: i know that. that's why i told you to remove gap form services section and put it over services. by do like this your services tab not find in first screen. and your problem got solved bro.